# Vim code folding - remap shortcut to toggle code folding

Tags: vim, vi, folding

Is there way to map e.g. F9 in .vimrc to toggle fold all/unfold all folds?

Comment: How about this https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442438-vim-tips-folding-fun ? You then can create a keymap in your .vimrc for different keystrokes (e.g. check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1) )

Comment: I had seen this, but it's not shown how to create a toggle - i.e. use the same key to fold all/open all.

Comment: Just `nnoremap [anything] zM` to fold everything and `nnoremap [anything] zR` to open all folds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***In your .vimrc file:***

Use the following command to set your desired keystroke (change `<C-F5>` which is Ctrl+F5 to the combination you like):

```
noremap <C-F5> :call UnrolMe()<CR>
```

The function `UnrolMe()` toggles all unrolling (i.e. it subsequently calls `zR` and `zM` commands)

```
let $unrol=0
function UnrolMe()
if $unrol==0
    :exe "normal zR"
    let $unrol=1
else
    :exe "normal zM"
    let $unrol=0
endif
endfunction
```

Change zR and zM to the unrolling commands of your choice (see https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442438-vim-tips-folding-fun for the list of commands). Hope this helps

Comment: Nice one, does the job!